# I am trying to do basic addition in c++ but large numbers are showing

Tags: c++, calculator

I am tryimg to do basic addition in c++ but a large number shows instead of the number thats suposed to show.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int sub = x + y;

    cout<<"Enter First number:"<<endl;
    cin>>x;
    cout<<"Enter second number:"<<endl;
    cin>>y;
    cout << "The sum is: "<< sub << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this it shows the sum as "6996596".

Comment: Don't ignore the warnings your compiler gives you.

Comment: Move `sub = x + y` after you get the values of `x` and `y`. As it stands you are initializing `sub` to `x + y`, whose values are undefined and thus you get undefined behavior. `C++` doesn't evaluate lazily.

Comment: Lazy evaluation. I wasn't even thinking of that, @user975989 . Good call. Worth spinning that up into an answer to explain where OP went wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sub` is being created and attributed before `x` and `y` are set. When you declare the variables but don't initialize then, you get unknown values from what you had previously on the stack.

If you move the `sub` variable attribution to after `x` and `y` were read from the terminal, the program would work correctly.

Comment: Thank you I understand now.

Answer (score 4):

You are computing your sum before accepting user input. Furthermore, you are summing two uninitialized variables, leading to undefined behavior.